# 3D triangulation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, maya, mesh, triangulation

Does anybody know what triangulation algorithm Maya uses? Lacking that, what would be the most probable algoritms to try? I tried a few simple off the top of my head (shortest/longest resulting edges, smallest minimum angle, smallest/biggest area), but they where all wrong. Is Delaunay the most plausible algoritm?

**Edit:** by the way, pseudo code on how to implement Delaunay for a 2D quad in 3D space to generate two triangles are more than welcome!

**Edit 2:** Unfortunately, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Visual_Delaunay_definition:_Flipping) is not the answer in 3D-space (only applicable in 2D).

Comment: Flipping (as in your link) is still commonly done on 3d meshes, but you may need extra constraints to avoid flipping quads that are extremely non-planar.

Comment: Yup, the quirk seems to be getting those constraints just right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like to second-guess people's intentions but if you are simply trying to get out of Maya what is shown in the viewport you can extract Maya's triangulation by starting with `MItMeshPolygon::getTriangles`.

(The corresponding normals and vertex colours are straightforwardly accessible. UVs require a little more effort -- I don't remember the details (all my Maya code is with my ex employer) but whilst at first glance it may seem like you don't have the data, in fact it's all there, just not conveniently.)

(One further note -- if your artists try hard enough, they can create polygons that crash Maya when `getTriangles` is called, even though they render OK and can be manipulated with the UI. This used to happen every few months, so it's worth bearing in mind but probably not worth worrying about too much.)

If you don't want to use the API or Python, then running `polyTriangulate` before exporting, then `undo` afterwards (to get back the original polygons) would let you examine out the triangulated mesh. (You may want or need to save the scene to a temp file, then reload it afterwards and use `file` to give it its old name back, if your export process does stuff that is difficult or impossible to undo.)

This is a bit hacky, but you're guaranteed to get the exact triangulation Maya is using. Rather easier than writing your own triangulation code, and almost certainly a LOT easier than trying to work out whatever Maya does internally...

Comment: Unfortunately I have mel, but no access to the C api (tool chain nearly done, I'm not replacing it). Sheesh, I'm getting increasingly annoyed by Maya's internals, since I sorta took the path of the reverse engineering idiot many months back. :)

Comment: I take it this IS what you're trying to do then? If you can't use the Python bindings to the C++ API, then maybe something like "polyTriangulate, export, undo" would help. (Alternatively, save scene to temp file, triangulate, export, reload, use "file" to give it its old name, in case your export does some random stuff that mucks with the undo queue.) A bit hacky, but rather easier than writing your own triangulation code, and I'm willing it bet it would be a LOT easier than trying to work out whatever Maya does internally...

Comment: Of course you're right. It took me two days and one night of trial-and-error to realize that. Thanks for the good advice anyway. :)

Comment: I've updated the answer so it includes the gist of my comment, for future searchers...

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking at [Voronoi and Delaunay Techniques](http://elliptic-pde.googlecode.com/hg-history/0d72f611e1ad6e1ad7a1ce435b9ed167572b99a8/papers/VoronoiDelaunay.pdf) by Henrik Zimmer.  I don't know if it's what Maya uses, but the paper describes some common techniques.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll check it out.

Comment: The link is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[Jonathan Shewchuk](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jrs/) has a very popular 2D triangulation tool called Triangle, and a 3D version should appear soon. He also has a number of papers on this topic that might be of use.

Comment: Fwiw, his triangle.c (2005) is 16k lines, including 1k help; enjoy

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/java/3d/delaunay.html) you can find an applet that demonstrates the Incremental, Gift Wrap, Divide and Conquer and QuickHull algorithms computing the Delaunay triangulation in 3D. Pointers to each algorithm are provided.